# php array dropdown field not insert into database mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am new in OOP PHP and I am still learning, I have a form where name of locations is populated through JQuery/HTML form using drop-down field with same name, my problem is when I try to insert in mysql database, I did not get the selected value,

```
        <div id="NCR" class="drop-down-show-hide">  
        <div class="field">
            <label for="region"> NCR </label>
            <select name="region" id="ncr region">
                <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
                <option value="1"> Region 1 </option>
                <option value="2"> Region 2 </option>
                <option value="3"> Region 3 </option>
            </select> 
        </div>  
    </div>


    <div id="CAR" class="drop-down-show-hide">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="field"> CAR </label>
            <select name="region" id="car region">
                <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
                <option value="4"> Region 4 </option>
                <option value="5"> Region 5 </option>
                <option value="6"> Region 6 </option>
            </select> 
        </div>  
    </div>


    <div id="region3" class="drop-down-show-hide">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="region"> CAMANABA </label>
            <select name="region" id="camanaba region">
                <option value="">-- Choose --</option>
                <option value="7"> Region 7 </option>
                <option value="8"> Region 8 </option>
                <option value="9"> Region 9 </option>
            </select> 
        </div>          
    </div>/HTML
```

PHP

```
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'apz_account' => array(
            'required' => true          
        ),
        'api_account' => array(
            'required' => true                      
        ),
        'wupos_tid' => array(
            'required' => true      
        ),
    ));

    if($validation->passed()){

        // check APZ account 
        $agent = DB::getInstance()->get('agent', array('apz_account', '=', Input::get('apz_account')));

        if(!$agent->count()){

                // check API account 
                $agent = DB::getInstance()->get('agent', array('api_account', '=', Input::get('api_account')));

                if(!$agent->count()){

                    $agent = new Agent();

                    try {


                        $agent->createAgentAccount(array(
                            'apz_account' => Input::get('apz_account'),
                            'api_account' => Input::get('api_account'),
                            'wupos_tid' => Input::get('wupos_tid'),
                            'region' => Input::get('region'),
                            'registered' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        ));


                        //  print_r($agent);
                         // Session::flash('success', 'You have registered successfully.');
                         // Redirect::to('../../index.php');


                        } catch(Exception $e){
                            die($e->getMessage());
                    }



                    } else {

                    echo Input::get('api_account'), ' account is already exists';
                }

            } else {

            echo Input::get('apz_account'), ' account is already exists';
        }


    } else {
        foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br>';    
        }

    }
}
```

Please advice. Thank you

Comment: please watch this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_LxkB-Pgf0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need unique names for each form element, with php you can use `region[]`.  this will give you an array in your server script.

Then when you get the value do `current(array_filter(Input::get('region')));`

Comment: Hi Thanks for comment, anyway it says in the error: Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given and urrent() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Comment: @JaysonLacson Did you change the name of your select form elements from `region` to `region[]`?

Comment: hi @Preston yes it is changed to region[].